# With date, how to specify a relative date when the specified date contains hours/minutes/seconds

Tags: linux, bash, date, scripting

In Bash, I want to compute the sum of a date (reception date) and a relative duration (retention duration).

For example, let :

```
reception_date="2017-01-02 12:34:56"
retention_duration="+2 days"
```

I expect to have:

```
expiration_date="2017-01-04--12-34-56"
```

Please note that the retention duration could be any valid relative date recognize by date, like `+X weeks` or `+X hours`.

My first grasp of the `date` info page lead me to use `date` like this

```
$ date -d '2017-01-02 12:34:56' +'%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'
2017-01-02--12-34-56
$ date -d '2017-01-02 12:34:56 +1 days' +'%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'
2017-01-03--12-34-56
$ date -d '2017-01-02 12:34:56 +2 days' +'%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'
2017-01-03--11-34-56
$ date -d '2017-01-02 12:34:56 +3 days' +'%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'
2017-01-03--10-34-56
$ date -d '2017-01-02 12:34:56 +4 days' +'%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'
2017-01-03--09-34-56
$ date -d '2017-01-02 12:34:56 +5 days' +'%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'
2017-01-03--08-34-56
```

As you can see, it seems to work fine for the `+1 days` but I get really irregular results for higher values.

The following example work as expected but are far less readable:

```
$ date -d '2017-01-02 +1 days 12:34:56' +'%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'
2017-01-03--12-34-56
$ date -d '2017-01-02 +2 days 12:34:56' +'%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'
2017-01-04--12-34-56
$ date -d '2017-01-02 +3 days 12:34:56' +'%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'
2017-01-05--12-34-56
$ date -d '+1 days 2017-01-02 12:34:56' +'%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'
2017-01-03--12-34-56
$ date -d '+2 days 2017-01-02 12:34:56' +'%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'
2017-01-04--12-34-56
$ date -d '+3 days 2017-01-02 12:34:56' +'%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'
2017-01-05--12-34-56
```

In the ideal solution, I would like to have :

- the correct expiration_date
- the readable relative date format (to explain to the user how and why this expiration date was computed).

I don't want to play with seconds conversions and stuff like that, the human-level readability of the solution is mandatory.

Thanks !

*More info*:

I'm on a RedHat, with date version:

```
$ date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.4
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie.
```

Comment: reception_date + 2 days, shouldn't that be "Tue Jan  3 "?  You have "Jan 4". Would this work, date -d "$reception_date + $retention_duration" +%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Revised answer

Following on from [this downstream bug-report comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/coreutils/+bug/51106/comments/3), I find you can do this by adding `now`:

```
$ date -d '2017-01-02 12:34:56 +2 days' +'%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'
2017-01-03--05-34-56      ## Oops
$ date -d '2017-01-02 12:34:56 now +2 days' +'%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'
2017-01-04--12-34-56      ## Much better
```

The `now` prevents `date` from parsing `+2` as a **timezone specification** *as well as* a **relative item**.  The difference between the two is explained in [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats), but the parser is apparently a bit odd in this situation.  I think "now" also reads oddly from a human standpoint, but it could be worse!

To see what `date` is doing, add the `--debug` flag to your `date` command.  See below for full explanation.

### Original answer

At least as of now (and still as of `date` version 8.26), you have to put the relative time items somewhere other than after the times.  The problem is that the `+ 1 hour` is being interpreted *both* as a relative time *and* as a timezone (!!!!).  The `--debug` flag to `date` is your friend.

Example of the right behavior (cygwin, `date` v8.26; my comments added):

```
$ date --debug -d '+1 hour 2017-01-19 12:34:56'    ## Relative before the time
date: parsed relative part: +1 hour(s)             ## OK
date: parsed date part: (Y-M-D) 2017-01-19
date: parsed time part: 12:34:56
date: input timezone: -05:00 (set from TZ="America/New_York" environment value)  ## Also OK
date: using specified time as starting value: '12:34:56'
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2017-01-19 12:34:56 TZ=-05:00'
date: '(Y-M-D) 2017-01-19 12:34:56 TZ=-05:00' = 1484847296 epoch-seconds
date: after time adjustment (+1 hours, +0 minutes, +0 seconds, +0 ns),
date:     new time = 1484850896 epoch-seconds
date: output timezone: -05:00 (set from TZ="America/New_York" environment value)  ## Still OK
date: final: 1484850896.000000000 (epoch-seconds)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2017-01-19 18:34:56 (UTC0)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2017-01-19 13:34:56 (output timezone TZ=-05:00)
Thu, Jan 19, 2017  1:34:56 PM                 ## A sensible result
```

Example of the wrong behavior:

```
$ date --debug -d '2017-01-19 12:34:56 + 1 hour'    # +1 hour at the _end_
date: parsed date part: (Y-M-D) 2017-01-19
date: parsed time part: 12:34:56 TZ=+01:00    ## TZ=+1 oops!
date: parsed relative part: +1 hour(s)        ## Parsed as a relative part also!
date: input timezone: +01:00 (set from parsed date/time string)    ##Oops
date: using specified time as starting value: '12:34:56'
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2017-01-19 12:34:56 TZ=+01:00'  ##Oops
date: '(Y-M-D) 2017-01-19 12:34:56 TZ=+01:00' = 1484825696 epoch-seconds
date: after time adjustment (+1 hours, +0 minutes, +0 seconds, +0 ns),
date:     new time = 1484829296 epoch-seconds
date: output timezone: -05:00 (set from TZ="America/New_York" environment value)  ## That's OK
date: final: 1484829296.000000000 (epoch-seconds)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2017-01-19 12:34:56 (UTC0)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2017-01-19 07:34:56 (output timezone TZ=-05:00)
Thu, Jan 19, 2017  7:34:56 AM     ## Bogus!
```

---

I am guessing that you are in a UTC+1 time zone, so date(1) interpreting `+1 days` as a UTC+1:00 timezone didn't hurt you.  **Edit** This [has been reported](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnulib/2009-09/msg00244.html) to [`gnulib`](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/gnulib) but does not appear to have been patched, so you may just have to go with the workaround you have already hit on.  The good news is that you do not have to present the same strings to users that you do to `date`.  For example,

```
rel="+2 days"
base="$(date)"
exp="$(date -d "$rel $base")
echo "$base $rel is $exp"
```

Note the order of `$base` and `$rel` is swapped in the last two lines.

Another alternative, of course, is to switch everything to UTC so you can say `date --debug -d '2017-01-19 12:34:56 Z + 1 hour'` (with `Z`) to force the relative part to be interpreted as such.

Comment: This is an excellent answer that also explains what I reported in [date processes first parameter incorrectly if it is not 1](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/211796/40596). Thanks for discovering the `--debug` flag!

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks for the compliment; happy to help!  I added another workaround (and upvoted your question on Unix.SE :) ).

Comment: This is even beetter, wow, the bug was reported 10 years ago! Probably their date is also broken so they did not notice the bug :P

Comment: Found the workaround by myself before finding this question and (long) answer : putting relative before absolute.